# ¿Cómo sumar datos buscados en php y MySql?

Tags: php, mysql, reporte

deseo poder sumar los valores de una busqueda

```
  function get_sales()
{
    
    
    $start_date = $this->input->get('start_date') ? $this->input->get('start_date') : NULL;
    $end_date = $this->input->get('end_date') ? $this->input->get('end_date') : NULL;

    $this->load->library('datatables');
    $this->datatables
    ->select("date,  id, total, product_tax,  total18, product_tax18, order_tax, grand_total")
    ->from('sales')
    ->group_by('id');


    if($start_date) { $this->datatables->where('date >=', $start_date); }
    if($end_date) { $this->datatables->where('date <=', $end_date); }
    


    
    echo $this->datatables->generate();

}
```

Ese es el código, donde me tira todos los valores de la tabla buscada, pero me gustaria realizar la suma de los valores que tire en la columna total, product_tax... etc. Totalizar cada columna.

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar la función `SUM()` de [MySQL](https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/func_mysql_sum.asp). Dentro del `SELECT` quedaría algo así (ejemplo para uno de los valores)

```
SUM(total) AS total_suma
```

En `total_suma` (este nombre puede ser el que quieras) quedará guardado el valor. Puedes replicar el ejemplo con el resto de los campos que desees sumar.